# Magento 2 admin top menus are not working?

Tags: magento2-dev-beta, admin-panel, topmenu

Recently I did a fresh installation of Magento 2 via composer. It was installed properly. But when I log into admin panel and try click any top menu, those are not redirecting. They haven't given any link for those menus. See the image below.

[image]

And in my browser (firefox) javascripts are enabled. See below.
[image]

How to resolve this? Am I missing anything?

NOTE: My magento version is `ver. 0.42.0-beta11`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try this http://www.dckap.com/blog/magento-2-admin-links-not-working-in-windows/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is related to a pre stable version of Magento 2: http://meta.magento.stackexchange.com/questions/907/magento-2-questions-tagged-beta-alpha-pre-alpha-etc-quo-vadis

Comment: Yes. I think it's better to close this question since many of us using the M2 stable version.

Answer (score 0):

In your website Static content (js and css etc.. ) not deployed.
To deploy static view files:

Log in to the Magento server as, or switch to, the Magento file system owner.
Delete the contents of `<your Magento install dir>/pub/static`.

Run the static view files deployment tool `<your Magento install dir>/bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy.`

Or

Follow this http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands.html

or

Run the below command:

```
<your Magento install dir>php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy    
<your Magento install dir>php bin/magento indexer:reindex
<your Magento install dir>php bin/magento cache:flush
```